# Extract colors out of Image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have an input that take in image url

My goal is to read that image and extract 2 hex colors out of it.

I researched and found this one : https://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/

I've tried integrated

**Image**

```
<img name="logo_path" id="skill-icon" src="/img/default.png" width="300px"><br><br>
```

**Input**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="logo_path" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
```

**JS**

```
var icon = $('#skill-icon');
icon.attr('src', $( "#url-logo" ).val());

$( "#url-logo" ).on('keyup',function(){


    var vibrant = new Vibrant(icon);
    var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
    for (var swatch in swatches)
        if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
            console.log(swatch, swatches[swatch].getHex())

    /*
     * Results into:
     * Vibrant #7a4426
     * Muted #7b9eae
     * DarkVibrant #348945
     * DarkMuted #141414
     * LightVibrant #f3ccb4
     */
});
```

I could not get it to work.

I kept getting

[image]

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

I put together a fiddle here :

https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/fkqx5gad/

[image]

How could I achieve this?

Comment: `icon` is jQuery object. Try `new Vibrant(icon[0])` to pass in native dom element

Comment: Let me try that in my latest Fiddle.

Comment: @charlietfl - with your suggestion seems working now.

Comment: I can see the hex in the console on this version. : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/fkqx5gad/14/

Comment: I still get this issue. `Vibrant.js:859 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.` Trying to fight it. If you know, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a result of the image being located at a different domain. Add the attribute crossDomain = "anonymous" to the image element.

Example:

```
<img src="test.jpg" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: Let me try that in Fiddle.

Comment: I can see the hex in the console on this version. : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/fkqx5gad/14/

Comment: I still get this issue. `Vibrant.js:859 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.` Trying to fight it.